# Pandas, groupby subgroups of maximum size

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with zipcodes and some other value columns for those zipcodes.
I want to group zipcodes with an arbitrary ID. (There can be 1-5 rows of data for each value of zip). To clarify: i want multiple rows with the same ID, so first row in ZIP A should have same ID as first row in ZIP B for example, but there should be no more than 49 rows for each ID.

So far so good, I am using groupby with cumcount+1 to achieve this goal. Like so:

```
df['id'] = df.groupby(['zip']).cumcount()+1
```

This does give me ID's ascending by zip. Like so:

| zip | id |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1 |
| 1000 | 2 |
| 1000 | 3 |
| 2000 | 1 |
| 2000 | 2 |

Which is exactly the output i need it gives all rows an ID between 1 and 5.
however, i have the limitation that for each ID, there can be no more than 49 rows. In current output ID 1, 2 and 3 are above this limit for example, as each zip has a least 1 row but fewer have 3,4 and 5 rows.

```
df.groupby('id').size()
```

| id | size |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 257 |
| 2 | 129 |
| 3 | 55 |
| 4 | 27 |
| 5 | 13 |

So there should be 13 different ID's in this case to accomodate the 49 max rows. I need to figure out how to split these groups up into smaller groups with a new id, value of the new id does not matter as long as it is consistent and the order of the rows within each zip does not matter either. Number of rows per zip can change so solution must be dynamic.
Logic i want to describe is something like:

```
for each row in zip assign incrementing ID column, if count of rows with the given ID value would be >49, then start a "new" id
```

I feel like i am missing something basic here, so far i have tried many pandas variations of groupby and also tried converting the df to a dict to iterate over it, but just cant seem to find a solid way to accomplish this.

Comment: groupby `id` again and cumcount // 49: `df.groupby('id').cumcount()//49`. This and `id` would give you the unique *new id*.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this assigns a unique ID to each row. While close this is not exactly what I need, because i dont want the ID to be unique, i want to have multiple rows with the same ID for each zip.
So first row of ZIP X should have the same id as the first row of ZIP Y, but the amount of rows per ID can not exceed 49.
My current thinking is that i could so something similar to your suggestion, but then concatenate the first ID (1-5) with the "sub" ID, and that would give me groups of max 49 size.